# MVC2 C# TextAreaFor contains ', ,'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, textarea, hidden

I am using MVC2 C#.

I have the following issue: if the !ModelState.IsValid, I send the user back to the invalid form where my textareas contain ',' or duplicates whatever is in the textarea.

```
<%=Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Address, new { cols = 42, rows = 4 })%>
<%=Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Address)%>
```

I pass this information inbetween forms, so I also have the value as a hidden at the bottom of the form, don't know another way of passing this information between forms (I have 8 forms in total which use 1 ViewModel).

I know the hidden is causing the issue but don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance for any help

Clare

Comment: Why do you have the Hidden field when it's value will already be in the Textarea?

Comment: I realised that. These have now been removed and it no longer duplicates the data. I thought as I was jumping from one form to another that I would have to store all values as hiddens, however I have found that I only have to store the values are the other form elements

Comment: Shouldn't you remove this question, given you have solved it yourself and it is unlikely others will encounter a similar issue? Since it was just a careless mistake on your part :). That keeps Stackoverflow more clean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had duplicated the values by having hidden fields on my aspx page. Once removed the textareas no longer contained ', ,' when the page was refreshed.

Comment: As an explanation, both the textarea and the hidden input had the same name. If there are two form inputs with the same name, browsers will submit them concatenated together with comma delimits.